# How to solve this operator equation numerically?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

I would like to know how one solves Sturm-Liouville problems on $(0,\infty)$ NUMERICALLY for the eigenvalues that are of the form

$$-f''(x)+\frac{1}{\sinh(x)^2}f(x)=\lambda f(x).$$

So even if there is a closed form solution to this problem, I would like to know how to treat singularities like this one with a computer. I also do not want to use programs, I am just interested in how to do this "by hand with a computer".

Comment: Presumably on $(0,\infty)$ rather than all of $\mathbb R$, since there's a singularity at $0$?

Comment: You may want to look at the existing [SLEIGN2 library](http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/).

Comment: I don't know much about Sturm-Liouville theory, but wouldn't you expect this equation to admit a nonzero eigenfunction for every $\lambda > 0$? Physically, this is the Schrodinger equation for a particle on $(0, \infty)$ experiencing a $1/\sinh^2$ potential spike at the origin. It is entirely unconfined to the right, and hence should happily be able to move to the right with any desired momentum $p$. This corresponds to solutions $f(x)$ asymptotic to $e^{ipx}$ as $x \to \infty$.